# Formal theories dealing with non-commutattive and non-transitive notion of equality

Tags: reference-request, logic, model-theory, philosophy

This question is inspired by a philosophical discussion which I don't want to bother you with.

As far as I know when we use (or define) the statement "$x$ is equal to $y$" in logic and ordinary mathematics we mean a "commutative" and "transitive" notion of $=$. i.e. We have

> $$\forall x,y~~~(x=y\leftrightarrow y=x)$$
>   $$\forall x,y,z~~~(x=y~\wedge~y=z\rightarrow x=z)$$

In some philosophical cases I came across some intuitively contradictory statements which could be consistent if we consider a "non-commutativity" or "non-transitive" binary relation $=$. In fact if we assume a weird situation between two objects $x$, $y$ such that *"$x$ is $y$ but $y$ is not $x$"* or have a situation that *"$x$ is $y$ and $y$ is $z$ but $x$ is not $z$"* we may get around of some contradictions. Note that it seems in theses type of using the $=$ a new intuition about the meaning of the word *"is"* is also needed because our ordinary point of view says that *"is"* is a commutative transitive verb.

**Question:** I would like to ask if anybody is aware of any formal logical system/theory  which deals with a non-commutative or non-transitive equality (identity) notion? If there is such a system I am more interested in its corresponding semantics and model theory. Any philosophical references about any use of non-commutative or non-transitive equality notion are also welcome.

Comment: Binary relations that are transitive and reflexive, but not necessarily symmetric, are called [pre-orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).  Your question is very vague, but even $\leq$ on the integers is a perfectly good example of "non-commutative equality", unless you say a lot more about what properties you're looking for.

Comment: But there's a good reason nobody speaks much of non-commutative "equality", which is that if we had some symbol $=$ that wasn't symmetric, then we could just define another symbol, $\sim$, by saying that $a\sim b$ exactly when both $a=b$ and $b=a$.  At that point, most people would just save time, and call $\sim$ "equality", and call "$=$", well, something else.

Comment: "Identity gives rise to challenging questions which are not altogether easy to answer." (*Sinn und Bedeutung*) $-$ It seems to me Frege will never be wrong about this.

Comment: Besides, what do you mean by "equality"? Do you mean 'identity' in the sense '$a$ is the same (object) as $b$'?  If so, I can't see how restrain commutativity would be appropriate. Can you be more clear about it?

Comment: @BBentzen Yes I mean "identity" but not in the usual sense. I edited the post. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get rid of the replacement property of "=" in order to talk about a non-symmetric equality, so long as you agree that a=a.  In other words, you'll have to get rid of the rule which allows you to replace either side of the "=" by the other side of the "=" wherever those *terms* appear.

Let all lower case letters qualify as terms.

Demonstration that if we have the replacement rule of inference for terms, that if a=a, then a=b if and only if b=a:

Suppose that a=a, and suppose that a=b.  Then replacing the left or first "a" with "b" in "a=a", we obtain b=a.  Thus, under the hypothesis that a=a, if a=b, then b=a.  Now suppose that b=a.  Replacing the right or second "a" with "b" in "a=a" we obtain "a=b".  Thus, if b=a, then a=b.  Therefore, if a=a, then a=b if and only if b=a.

Or more symbolically $\forall$a $\forall$b {(a=a)$\rightarrow$[(a=b)↔(b=a)]}

This effectively rules out truth tables as possible in a relevant model, since truth tables all rely on having a rule of replacement (even though the formulas in propositional logic are not terms... they behave just like terms in a certain sense).  So, the underlying propositional logic will end up as infinite-valued.  But you can't use say Lukasiewicz infinite-valued logic or any fuzzy logic that I know of either, since that also has a rule of replacement for "=" as permissible.

It's not at all clear how anything could get computed without a rule of replacement also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best source to start an investigation on the notion of "equality", its history and its rules (also other basic laws of thought) would be here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought